# Date calculation in Java

Tags: java, date

I have date of birth of a person. There is one more date given say, d1. I want to know if the person reaches age 40 during last one year from d1 date. Date is in 'yyyyMMdd' format

I think of something related to finding out the time and do some subtraction and then check if it is 40 or not etc.

What is the best way to do this calculation?

Comment: **Never** use "urgent" in SO question. Just a friendly advice.

Comment: What format is your date in? Is it a String?

Comment: It's in yyyyMMdd format

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588640/date-difference-calculation-in-java) SO question/answer shows how to calculate the days between two dates.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways how you can achieve this, from using milliseconds and simple substraction and conversion to years to using [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) objects.

You also might want to have a look at [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) (a handy 3rd party java api to handling with dates) and

Here is a way to do it using [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

```
@Test
public void compareDates() throws ParseException {
    Date d1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse("20130317");
    Date birthDate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse("19700101");
    Date birthDate2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse("19900101");

    GregorianCalendar cd1 = new GregorianCalendar();
    cd1.setTime(d1);
    cd1.set(Calendar.YEAR, cd1.get(Calendar.YEAR)-1); // one year ago

    GregorianCalendar cbd1 = new GregorianCalendar();
    cbd1.setTime(birthDate1);

    GregorianCalendar cbd2 = new GregorianCalendar();
    cbd2.setTime(birthDate2);

    Assert.assertTrue((cd1.get(Calendar.YEAR) - cbd1.get(Calendar.YEAR)) > 40);
    Assert.assertFalse((cd1.get(Calendar.YEAR) - cbd2.get(Calendar.YEAR)) > 40);
}
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Likewise, the Joda-Time project is in maintenance mode, with the team advising migration to java.time.

Answer (score 0):

**`getTime()` will return the time in milliseconds.**

```
long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime(); // the difference in milliseconds
```

I'll leave it as a practice to convert these milliseconds into years.

Comment: You downvoted, because? Please don't tell me because of the *exercise*.

Comment: There are so many things you can do wrong when you do date calculations. Days, years are not always of the same length etc., so simply don't do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DateTester{

    private static final long MILLISECONDS_IN_YEAR = 31556926279L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Note:  These constructors are deprecated
            //I'm just using them for a quick test

    Date startDate = new Date(2013,03,01);
    Date birthday = new Date(1981,01,1981);//Returns false
    Date birthday2 = new Date(1972,03,20); //Returns true
    Date birthday3 = new Date(1973,02,27); //Test edge cases  //Returns false
    Date birthday4 = new Date(1972,02,27); //Test edge cases, //Returns false


    System.out.println(withinYear(birthday, startDate,40));
    System.out.println(withinYear(birthday2, startDate,40));
    System.out.println(withinYear(birthday3, startDate,40));
    System.out.println(withinYear(birthday4, startDate,40));


        System.out.println(withinYear(birthday, startDate,40));
        System.out.println(withinYear(birthday2, startDate,40));
    }

    public static boolean withinYear(Date birthday, Date startDate, int years){
        if(birthday.before(startDate)){
            long difference = Math.abs(birthday.getTime() - startDate.getTime());
            int yearDifference = (int) (difference/MILLISECONDS_IN_YEAR);
            return yearDifference  < (years +1) && yearDifference >= years;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The other Answers use the troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

## Using java.time

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate birthDate = LocalDate.parse( "19540123" , DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ) ;
LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.parse( "20110317" , DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE );

LocalDate dateWhen40YearsOld = birthDate.plusYears( 40 ) ;
Boolean turning40WithinYear = 
    ( ! dateWhen40YearsOld.isBefore( d1 ) )         // "If not before" is a short way of saying "is equal to or later than". 
    && 
    dateWhen40YearsOld.isBefore( d1.plusYears( 1 ) )
;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).